# Can't create new RavenDB database with Ruby rest_client

Tags: ruby, ravendb

I'm trying to create a new RavenDb using the Ruby rest_client but I continually get 400 errors.  Below is my simple script which I'm running on the local machine.  I have also tried the PUTS command but it results in the same error.  Thank you for your help!

Windows Server 2012
RavenDB version 2261

```
require 'rest_client'  
require 'json'

config = Hash.new  
config["Settings"] = Hash.new  
config["Settings"]["Raven/DataDir"] = "~\\Databases\\TempWebState2"  
config["Settings"]["Raven/ActiveBundles"] = "PeriodicBackup;DocumentExpiration"  

RestClient.post "http://localhost:8081/Raven/Databases/TempWebState2", config.to_json
```

Comment: Are you actually getting a `400` error, or are you getting a `4xx` error?

Comment: It is a 400.  Here is a clip of the Raven debug logging.  


Raven.Database.Server.HttpServer,Debug,Request #   1: PUT     -   389 ms - <system>   - 400 - /Raven/Databases/TempWebState2,

Comment: Tried to format that better but failed.

Comment: Have you looked at what a `400` error is?

Comment: It's a Bad Request but I'm not sure where I'm messing up.

Comment: Why don't you view what your request looks like and see how the syntax looks.

Comment: Using Fiddler, I see that Raven is using the admin/databases/TempWebState2 url.  I tried this and am now getting a authentication error (401).  Anyway to pass the user and password?

Answer (score 2):

To fix this I had to change the RestClient command to **put** and change the URL to **admin/databases/**.  Also Raven/AnonymousAccess had to be set to **Admin**

```
RestClient.put "http://localhost:8081/admin/databases/TempWebState2", config.to_json
```